# How to delete nodes in the middle and end of a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to delete the odd numbers that are randomly generated (see `oddsOnly`), and then print the list in reverse order. I can delete odds that may pop up at the beginning of the list, but I cannot find a way to delete anything after that.

I have tried various forms of if and while loops. Too many different ways for me to remember or list them all.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int element;
    Node *next;
    Node *previous;
};

// Function headers
int takeNumber(int);
int writeFile(int);
struct Node *readFile(Node *&, int);
void printBackward(Node *);
struct Node *oddsOnly(Node *&, int);
void deleteList(Node *);

// Main
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check to see if the user passed us the size to make the list.
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        // Check to see if what the user passed us is in fact a valid number.
        // Here we attempt to assign what was passes in to us to an int variable
        int Size = atoi(argv[1]);

        // Now we check a few things. If the !Size tells us whether or not the
        // assignment above was successful. If the size is less than 20 or 
        // greater than 100, the input did not follow the instructions. In 
        // either case we ask the user to enter another number with the printed
        // instructions of it must be between 20 and 100.
        if (!Size || Size < 20 || Size > 100)
        {
            Size = takeNumber(Size);
        }

        // Create the pointer for Head. This is used to keep track of the beginning
        // of the list.
        Node *Head = new Node;

        if (Head == NULL)
        {
            cout << "fatal error: could not create Head node." << endl;
            return(1);
        }

        Head = NULL;

        // If we are here, the head node was created successfully. As this is 
        // currently also the last node in the list, set the pointer to NULL.
        //Head->next = NULL;

        writeFile(Size);

        readFile(Head, Size);

        // When you allocate memory with new or malloc, you should always clean
        // free up the memory when you are through.
        deleteList(Head);
    }

    else
    {
        int Size = 0;

        Size = takeNumber(Size);

        // Create the pointer for Head. This is used to keep track of the beginning
        // of the list.
        Node *Head = new Node;

        if (Head == NULL)
        {
            cout << "fatal error: could not create Head node." << endl;
            return(1);
        }

        Head = NULL;

        // If we are here, the head node was created successfully. As this is 
        // currently also the last node in the list, set the pointer to NULL.
        //Head->next = NULL;

        writeFile(Size);

        readFile(Head, Size);

        oddsOnly(Head, Size);

        // When you allocate memory with new or malloc, you should always clean
        // free up the memory when you are through.
        deleteList(Head);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// Function to take input (size) from the user
int takeNumber(int Size)
{
    while (Size < 20 || Size > 100)
    {
        // Output specific instructions to the user.
        cout << endl << "Please inter a number between 20 and 100 (inclusive). " << endl;

        // Take a given input from the user.
        cin >> Size;

        // Set a while loop so that if the incorrect input is given, the user will
        // be asked to enter a different input untill it fits the given discription
        // in the instructions.
        if (cin.fail() || Size < 20 || Size > 100)
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            // Print error message and ask for another input.
            cout << "Input is not between 20 and 100 (inclusive). " << endl;
            cout << "Please try again. " << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    // Return the input.
    return Size;
}

// Function to write random numbers to a binary file
int writeFile(int size)
{
    // Create and open the file you will write to.
    ofstream WriteFile;
    WriteFile.open("numbers.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);

    // Make sure to print an error message if the file was not created.
    if (!WriteFile)
    {
        cout << "Could not create/open binary file for writing. " << endl << endl;
        return (1);
    }

    // Seed the random fuction with the time from the computer.
    srand(int(time(NULL)));

    // create a variable to store the random variable gernerated.
    int number = 0;

    // Create a loop to generate some random data and store it in
    // the number variable. Then write the number to the to the binary
    // file.
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        // Generate a random number between 0 and 99.
        number = (rand() % 100);

        // Write the number to the binary file.
        WriteFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&number), sizeof(int));
    }

    WriteFile << endl;

    // Close the binary file.
    WriteFile.close();

    return(0);
}

// Function to read the binary file and create a linked list.
struct Node *readFile(Node *&Head, int Size)
{
    // Create and open a read binary file
    ifstream ReadFile;
    ReadFile.open("numbers.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);

    // Check to make sure file has been created and opened.
    if (!ReadFile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open the binary file for reading. " << endl << endl;
    }

    int Data = 0;

    int counter = 1;

    while (ReadFile)
    {
        ReadFile.read((char*)&Data, sizeof(int));

        if (ReadFile.eof())
        {
            break;
        }

        if (Head == NULL)
        {
            Node *tmp = new Node;

            if (tmp == NULL)
            {
                cout << "fatal error: could not create tmp node" << endl;
            }

            tmp->element = Data;
            tmp->next = NULL;
            tmp->previous = NULL;
            Head = tmp;

            counter = counter + 1;
        }

        else if (Head != NULL)
        {
            Node *current = new Node;

            if (current == NULL)
            {
                cout << "fatal error: could not create current node" << endl;
            }

            current = Head;

            while (current->next != NULL)
            {
                current = current->next;
            }

            struct Node *temp = new Node;

            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                cout << "fatal error: could not create temp node" << endl;
            }

            temp->element = Data;
            temp->next = NULL;
            temp->previous = current;
            current->next = temp;

            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    // Close the file
    ReadFile.close();

    oddsOnly(Head, Size);

    printBackward(Head);

    cout << endl;

    return Head;
}

// Function to read the numbers.bin file and put numbers in reverse order
void printBackward(Node *Head)
{
    // We now have a list. We can traverse the list and print the elements.
    // We have the head, we create a current or tmp node pointer to set it
    // equal to head.
    Node *temp;
    temp = Head;

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    // We can use a counter to format the output on the console
    int counter = 1;

    // This is our loop to traverse the list. We start at head, and go until
    // we reach the null pointer of the last node.
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        // This prints the number in the node, then a tab separator to the 
        // console.
        cout << temp->element << "\t";

        // This is used for formatting the output on the screen. In this case,
        // after every five nodes have been printed, we insert a newline and 
        // reset the counter to 0.
        if (counter % 5 == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
            counter = 0;
        }

        // We advance the tmp or current pointer to the next value and increment the counter.
        temp = temp->previous;
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
}

// Function to weed out the odd numbers in the list
struct Node *oddsOnly(Node *&Head, int size)
{
    int counter = 1;

        while (Head->element % 2 == 0)
        {
            struct Node *temp = Head;

            Head = Head->next;
            Head->previous = NULL;
            delete(temp);

            return Head;

            counter = counter + 1;
        }

        Node *tmp = Head;

        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            Node *current = Head;

            while (current->element % 2 != 0 && current->next->next != NULL)
            {
                current = current->next;
                tmp = current->next;
            }

            current->previous->next = current->next;
            current->next->previous = current->previous;
            delete(current);


            struct Node *current1 = Head;

            while (current1->next != NULL)
            {
                current1 = current1->next;
            }

            if (current1->element % 2 == 0)
            {
                current1->previous->next = NULL;
                delete(current1);
            }
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }

    cout << endl;

    return Head;
}

// Function to delete the link list.
void deleteList(Node *Head)
{
    Node *tmp;

    // Loop through the list, deleting one node at a time. We set tmp equal
    // to the node after head, delete head and then set head equal to tmp.
    while (Head != NULL)
    {
        tmp = Head->next;
        delete(Head);
        Head = tmp;
    }
}
```

I am looking for a list that allows 5 integers before starting a new line, and that has only odd values from the linked list.

I have gotten a lot of error messages displaying 0xDDDDDDDD in the `oddsOnly` function. at this point though, I am only seeing that it is not deleting the evens after the first node in the list.

Comment: There's a lot of code here, but none of it seems to include a delete() function.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [following diagram](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/doubly-linked-list):

[image]

To delete node B from the list, set `A.Next` to `A.Next.Next`, set `C.Prev` to `C.Prev.Prev`, and free node B.

To delete node D from the list, set `C.Next` to `C.Next.Next` (which is null), and free node D.

Make sure you *write a function* that does this.  Your code suggests that you're not fully taking advantage of the encapsulation and "divide and conquer" strategy that functions provide.

**Further Reading**
[Delete a node in a Doubly Linked List](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-node-in-a-doubly-linked-list/)

Answer (score 0):

Stealing Roberts great picture

[image]

I don't quite agree with his description (it is correct though just a bit complicated when written in English).

```
 Node*  x = findNodeToDelete();
 if (x == nullptr) {   // Check to make sure you have an actual node to delete.
     return;
 }

 if (x->next != nullptr) {
     x->next->prev = x->prev;
 }
 if (x->prev != nullptr) {
     x->prev->next = x->next;
 }
 else {
     Head = x->next;
 }
 // Now you have unlinked the node from the list.

 x->next = nullptr;   // Optional if node has a complex destructor may be worth it.
 x->prev = nullptr;   // Optional 

 // Now release the node you are deleting.
 delete x;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know there are 3 situations in deleting being
1 - head
2 - middle 
3- end 
 I think you covered the first one lest proceed to the second one 
lets say you are in a traversing loop

```
while( cur != NULL ){
...
cur = cur -> next;
```

let's look at the middle of the node for second case 
For deletion in the middle, you should know the previous node and the next node of to deleted node and you should bind them together. Luckily you both have previous and next in doubly linked list.
so lets add a statement to a code

```
if ( cur -> data == oddNumber ){
   Node* prev = cur -> prev;
   Node* next = cur -> next;
   prev -> next =  cur -> next;
   delete cur; 
   cur = cur -> next;
 }
```

that was for the middle, and for the end (3 rd case) you can simply check if the next node of the node is NULL and delete it peacefully.